# Sending Data to another view with Segue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have some User Info from a Login Screen that i would like to pass to another view. I setup the segue and there is still no data transfer. How can a i transfer the users info from one view to the second?

Here is some of my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "sendHomePage") {
        let destinationVC:HomeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as HomeViewController
        destinationVC.nameFromLogin = nameOfUser
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "sendName") {
        let destinationVC:ScheduleViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ScheduleViewController
        destinationVC.nameOfUserFromView = nameOfUser
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code Should work. In case it doesn't you should properly check the identifiers of the segue. One more method is to use notification centre for inter-controller communication